# Term for words that don't have a meaning on their own

Tags: linguistics

Is there a term for words, phrases, etc. that on their own don't add any semantic information to a sentence.

For example "Well" in "Well, I'm about to tell you" or "I mean" ind "I mean, I never met him". If you just remove those from the sentence no information is lost, but they sort of  change the connotation or "feel" for what is said. I'm sure there are more examples for this and a better definition than what I've come up with.

All I want to know is if there is a name for words and phrases serving that particular role.

Comment: [filler words or interjections]

Comment: Hello, Vyralator. Does this answer your question? [What do you call superfluous filler words like 'So' 'Anyhow' 'Anyway'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/257527/what-do-you-call-superfluous-filler-words-like-so-anyhow-anyway) Or [What is the term for words like 'look' and 'listen' followed by a comma at the](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112846/what-is-the-term-for-words-like-look-and-listen-followed-by-a-comma-at-the-s/223116#223116) (there are others). Various discourse markers / pragmatic markers (qv).

Comment: ... See also [Adjective for a type of conversation where no real information is conveyed but](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/319390/adjective-for-a-type-of-conversation-where-no-real-information-is-conveyed-but-r/337177#337177) and [What's the name for {a part of} speech which is not quite rhetorical but not expected to be answered?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/203738/whats-the-name-for-a-part-of-speech-which-is-not-quite-rhetorical-but-not-expe/203740#203740) ('phatic').

Answer (score 0):

Possibly [phatic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/phatic) communication. Phatic communication isn't about conveying semantic information, but rather to maintain social bonds.

> : of, relating to, or being speech used for social or emotive purposes rather than for communicating information

Comment: Filler speech is a subset of [phatic communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phatic_expression), which also includes things like "hello", "goodbye", "excuse me", "how are you", "pardon?", small talk, talk about talk, etc.